# XAML DataContext

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

This works

```
<Border>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Info1}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.Info2}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

but this doesn't

```
<Border DataContext="Foo">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info1}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info2}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

My understanding is the if you set datacontext for a parent, the children would be able to bind to the properties. Is Border not a good element to be a parent?
I'm very new to data binding in XAML. Can someone tell me why the second snipped doesn't work and point me in the right direction?

Comment: I find out it @ProfessorChaos, that's why I remove my comment

Comment: @ArsenMkrt thanks. upvoted all. I'll accept answer as soon as the system lets me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<Border DataContext="{Binding Foo}">
```

Without binding the datacontext of your border is just "Foo" string, which doesn't have any Info1, Info2 properties

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Let me hazard a guess here that you still need to *bind* to the `DataContext`, rather than simply applying what looks to XAML like a literal string of "Foo":

```
<Border DataContext="{Binding Foo}">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info1}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info2}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, you should write:

```
<Border DataContext="{Binding Foo}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info1}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info2}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Border DataContext="{Binding Foo}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info1}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Info2}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

The above will now imply that `Info1` and `Info2` will exist on the `DataContext`, which in this case is now bound to `Foo`.

Setting the `DataContext` as you did; `<Border DataContext="Foo">` would cause the DataContext property to return *Foo*.

```
<Border DataContext="Foo">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

If you try the above code both `TextBlock`'s will return *Foo*.